how do i resolve this Error 405 : method not allowed
db.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure MySQL
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = "localhost"
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = "root"
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ""  # Add your MySQL root password here if applicable
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = "studentsphere"

# Initialize MySQL
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get form data
        username = request.form['username']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        confirm_password = request.form['confirm_password']

        # Validate form inputs
        if password != confirm_password:
            return "Passwords do not match."

        try:
            # Insert into database
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            query = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
            cur.execute(query, (username, email, password))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()

            return redirect(url_for('login'))  # Redirect to a login page after successful registration

        except Exception as e:
            return f"An error occurred: {e}"

    return render_template('register.html')

@app.errorhandler(405)
def method_not_allowed(e):
    return jsonify({'error': 'Method Not Allowed'}), 405

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')  # Placeholder for the login functionality

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


register.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='register.css') }}">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #575048; padding: 10px;">
    <div class="container">
        <header class="header">
            <h1>Studentsphere</h1>
            <nav class="nav-links">
                <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
                <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Log In</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('register') }}" class="registration-form">

                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required/>
        
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required/>
        
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required/>
        
                <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" required/>
        
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
            <a href="{{ url_for('base') }}" class="home-button">Home</a>
        </main>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>

When I try visiting http://127.0.0.1:5000/register and submit my data I get 405 error: method not allowed.
my terminal show this: "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 405 -
am using windows 10 machine with brave browser
my browser console shows this
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
what am I doing wrong ?

Try printing inside the def register() function, See if the code even got there.

I can only guess that this is not the actual code running on your machine.  Either you edited the code and forgot to save it, or this code is deployed on a different port, or something like that.

Can you show us how you are running this code?  Maybe you forgot to run it on port 5000?

It's possible that the error isn't really 405 - and that's what it shows after the function - @app.errorhandler(405). Try deleting it and see what error you get back.
